# Find $k$ maximally-orthogonal/minimally-correlated vectors on an $n$-sphere

Tags: euclidean-geometry, inner-products, spheres

**EDIT**: In physics, this is equivalent to the problem of finding the equilibrium configuration of $k$ electrons arranged on an $n$-sphere. This is also known as the Thomson problem.

Does anyone know of a way to find a set of vectors $(v_i)_{i=1}^k$ on the unit $n$-sphere such that they are maximally orthogonal to each other? That is, given the function for minimal angle between $k$ $n$-vectors, $f:(\mathbb{R}^n)^k\to\mathbb{R} $:

$$f(u_1, u_2, \dots, u_k)=\left|\min_{1\le i<j\le k}\angle(u_i, u_j)\right|$$
I look for a subset of the unit $n$-sphere that maximizes that function:

$$ (v_i)_{i=1}^k:=\arg \max \{f(u_1, u_2, \dots, u_k)\mid u_i\in S^n\}$$

There's obviously a degeneracy in the choice of the $u_i$'s, but that isn't an issue. For $k\le n$ the problem is simple, so assume $k>n$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You may want to consult the topic of "spherical codes and designs"

Comment: Did I misunderstand something? If the $v_i$ are equal, or at least two of them, the minimum angle is $0$, right? Do you mean the inner product?

Comment: @Matija. There was a different problem with the formulation. I want $\arg \max$. I think that this formulation holds.

Comment: It's confusing that this is called maximally orthogonal. For $k=2$ we would get $\pi$, for any $v_2=-v_1$.

Comment: @Matija you are correct. The naming is more appropriate for the $k>n$ case where it does mean that (and that's the case that I care about).